# How to split a array in n character from right side python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a binary array having m characters, I want to divide it into the block of n characters from right side using python.

Comment: Please provide a **[mcve]**.

Comment: I have an array of character like this 11000010110001001100011. I want to divide it from the right side like 01100011,01100010,1100001

Comment: @ZainMalik. Please edit your question and show exactly how you create the array of characters.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose you have an array `arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6]`, and `m=3`.

If you can break it up into divisible chunks, then:

```
back_m_iter = zip(*([iter(reversed(arr))]*m))
```

Gives you an array grouped by `m` elements from the back.

If you want the list, simply:

```
back_m_list = list(back_m_iter)

output: [(6,5,4),(3,2,1)]
```

If you want to fill the empty spots with `None`'s for nondivisible arrays(say `arr` is extended by 1):

```
from itertools import zip_longest
back_m_iter = zip_longest(*([iter(reversed(arr))]*m), fillvalue=None)

output: [(7,6,5),(4,3,2),(1,None,None)]
```

You can replace `None` with 0's if you wanted the rest to be 0's.

**EDIT:** Just saw your comment, here's a revision (misunderstood your question):

```
back_m_list = [x[::-1] for x in back_m_iter]

output: [(4,5,6),(1,2,3)]
```

You can also do:

```
back_m_iter = reversed(list(zip(*([iter(arr)]*m))))

output: [(4,5,6),(1,2,3)]
```